# How to Integrate Python with Visual C# Windows Form Application without using IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, winforms

It is easy to develop a console application in python with Microsoft Visual Studio. But **I want to integrate python with visual c# windows form application.**
IronPython is the only option in C# to create a windows form application with python. But the problem is that **ironpython is very limited and most of python libraries are not supported(like sklearn).**
I have installed Anaconda3 with python 3.6 which contains most of the packages and libraries of python.
I was wondering if there was a way in which I could **integrate anaconda3 python environment in windows form application of c#?**
I want to run a python script through a button in Windows Form Application from Visual C# and display the results in a text area.